# Apple developer registering bundle ID

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle-identifier, apple-developer

Today is my first day using my paid account (purchased it today), however, ive been building an app with a free provisional account for the past 2 months. I was using a totally different itunes account.

Now, since i paid for a developer account, i am attempting to register for a new app id in my developer portal so that i can configure push notifications. However, when i try to add the bundle ID i have been using, it gives me an error

**"There were errors in the data supplied. Please correct and re-submit.
An App ID with Identifier 'com.2four.***' is not available. Please enter a different string."**

I assumed i would be able to register my new app with the bundle ID.

*The main reason i want to use the same bundle ID is because i have already build a firebase backend which uses the same bundle ID in the project, and i dont want to have to create a new firebase project.* Please, any suggestions or solutions? Has this happened to anybody before.. Thank you in advance

Comment: i think if you had created your developer account at your free account id(you were using previously)  you might not got this issue. :) **Note** its just an assumption i haven't tried this :D

Answer (score 1):

To fix this - after hours of failed attempts. I was able to fix the problem by simply going into Firebase, my app, and creating a new app with the newer bundle ID. If you already have firebase running, no need to delete pods or erase anything, simply just create the new app, add the Google P list file, delete the old Google p list, and delete the old app from Firebase, and you'll be set to go